# Can the private key inside a yubikey be known to anyone, e.g. the NSA?

Tags: yubikey

I wonder if the NSA can force Yubico (or their secure element chip supplier), a US company located in Palo Alto, California, to hand over the private keys stored in the secure element of the yubikey by means of a national security letter?
Or is that impossible due to the hardware design of the secure element?

Comment: Unless you have a means to inspect the hardware, obviously you cannot know for sure whether you got a backdoored version. It is anyone's guess whether Yubico knowingly or unknowingly ships such insecure versions, similar to asking whether Windows has any security flaws remaining after fixing the latest bugs: it's impossible to answer that with certainty and any answer will be an opinion. Whether NSLs are a legal means to coerce Yubico would rather be a question for a lawyer or the law stackexchange site.

Comment: @Luc: thank you for your answer. exactly what i think: unless everything is open-sourced, its guessing. i was hoping that some expert knows how the private key is generated / burned / stored into the secure element.
what i found is that yubico uses a secure element from infineon technologies AG, that - according to wikipedia - seems to be a german company. But does that help? I guess not, because the chips probably are not produced (and programmed?) in germany...

Comment: "*unless everything is open-sourced*" And even then, who's to say that they shipped you what was specified in the source specification? That it doesn't have vulnerabilities intentionally included in hard-to-spot ways? That the NSA didn't replace your shipment with a fake? A lot of cryptography stuff comes down to trust. It doesn't really help to find an expert who knows how the key is burned because, even if it happens all on-chip, who's to say the chip doesn't have a method to export the key and turns off that method after first use?

Answer (score -1):

I think not, because accordingly this link, even NSA, and others government agencies like FBI uses Yubikey. https://www.yubico.com/industries/federal/:

> YubiKeys are widely deployed in the US Government with over 150 unique
> implementations including US Army, US Navy, US Air Force, US Marine
> Corps, US Space Force, DoD Missile Defense Agency, Federal Bureau of
> Investigation (FBI), National Security Agency (NSA), Department of
> Energy and more.

In contrary, the reverse would also be possible: a not-well-intentioned Yubico internal could "leak" top secret information to press, crime, hackers, etc

Comment: I wish that people who downvote, *especially new contributors*, would add an explanation of how to improve the answer... Anyway, my own opinion on this answer is that Yubico could just bake special batches for special customers. Having the USA government as a customer is not a reason why they must be secure for anyone else.

Comment: This answer is just bad logic that misses the much better detail: DoD-approved Yubikeys are the 5 series, which are "FIPS 140-2 validated (Overall Level 2, Physical Security Level 3.)" And this answer doesn't address the possibility of Yubikey gaining access to keys in the first place ...

Comment: I honestly apreciate your correction, but I didnt understand when you said: "Yubikey gaining access to keys in the first place". Its something like a backdoor at the devices?